# MatDialog Open next dialog when previous was closed - forLoop or stream

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dialog

How to open next dialog from stream, only when previous was closed? I mean I don't want to open all dialogs in a row when I gets values of stream.

```
        const arraySource = from(res);

        arraySource.pipe().subscribe(code => {
          console.log('value: ', code);

          const description = this.locale.getDescription(code);
          const config      = new MatDialogConfig();
                config.data = {code: code, description: description.value};

          this.validationDialogRef = this.dialog.open(ValidationDialog, config);
          this.validationDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
                console.log("data returned from mat-dialog-close is ", this.validationDialogRef, data);

          });

        })
```

When I use take(1) operator I get only first element from Array in dialog., without take(1), all dialogs will appear. There is some method to run scheluder when previous dialog was closed>

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concat`. This will trigger the next observable once the previous has finished:

```
concat(
  ...res.map((code) => of(void 0).pipe(
    concatMap(() => {
      const description = this.locale.getDescription(code);
      const config = new MatDialogConfig();
      config.data = {code: code, description: description.value};

      this.validationDialogRef = this.dialog.open(ValidationDialog, config);

      return this.validationDialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
        tap((data) => {
          console.log("data from mat-dialog-close:", this.validationDialogRef, data);
        })
      );
    })
  ))
).susbcribe(() => {
  // all dialogs have been processed
});
```

If you want to use `concatAll`, you can do it like this. Which is basically the same. You can also use it with `defer`:

```
from(res).pipe(
  map((code) => defer(() => {
    const description = this.locale.getDescription(code);
    const config = new MatDialogConfig();
    config.data = {code: code, description: description.value};

    this.validationDialogRef = this.dialog.open(ValidationDialog, config);

    return this.validationDialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        console.log("data from mat-dialog-close:", this.validationDialogRef, data);
      })
    );
  }),
  concatAll()
).subscribe(() => {
  // all dialogs have been processed
});
```

Comment: Thank you for response, I'm not sure I understand you well. I mean, I want to trigger next dialog, when previous is on afterClose action, there should be call of new one? (my pipe was empty because iv removes take(1) operator)
When I'v tried this code, works similar to mine -> all(two) dialogs was in same time on screen. I try make something like "takeNext" in afterclose to invoke other stream val. I was thinking on concat but Idk how to take advantage of it well.

Comment: @UlandNimblehoof you are right. There may be another way using `concatAll` but I don't see it right now. Anyways, I've updated my answer by using a `of` which will make it wait opening the dialog until the previous closes